# Is there better solution to map lots of fields entity into two tables?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting data with 50 fields. How to map into two tables in jpa, in which I required only three fields and rest of fields I need to only pass to downstream?

This is for a new spring data jpa, running H2 db project. In the past, I’ve tried  to map all 50 fields in one entity table. But I require only 3 essential fields from those 50 fields to process of last 5000 records from db.

```
   @Entity
   class SingleCustomer{  

    //ID field
    // 3 fields only these fields I am using to process my data from db

    //47 fields just to pass to another service without any process

    }
```

To improve performance of my application which approach I should take?
Are there any other ways to improve application performance like split into two entities and join on one to one when needs to send another service.

Comment: You mean, not select all the fields from db while query?

Comment: Yes. I mean to say to that I require only three fields from stream to do some processing rest of the fields I need to pass to another service in kafka.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you can split all the fields into two entities and join on one-to-one relationShip. But you should notice that field with one-to-one relationShip is loaded eagerly by default, you should mark it as lazy-loaded to improve performance.

Comment: Exactly I was thinking about the same solution use one to one mapping then use lazy when fetching

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate entity for fields you don't need together with a `@OneToOne` association is one way of doing that, as @Lebecca pointed out.

However, if you'd rather keep all the properties in one entity, you could turn on Hibernate bytecode enhancement, which enables support for `@Basic(fetch = LAZY)`. If you want, you should also be able to combine such an approach with using a `@SecondaryTable` to store the properties you don't usually need.

See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/pc/BytecodeEnhancement.html) for more info, including info on how to fine-tune the lazy loading behavior with enhancement enabled.